# How to call the override pause method dynamically from Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, overriding, lifecycle, onpause

I create a Libgdx game and I want to know if it is possible to call the override pause method lifecycle with Libgdx?

Here is my pause method lifecycle in my class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
        chrono.pause();
        //Display a pause menu
    }
}
```

And I want to call the lifecycle method when I click on the pause image:

```
    imagePause = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pause.png")));
    imagePause.setSize(pauseSize, pauseSize);
    imagePause.setPosition(width - pauseSize, height - pauseSize);
    imagePause.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //Something like this? :
            Gdx.app.pause(); //Doesn't exist

            //I don't want to call manually the pause method like this       
            //because it doesn't pause Libgdx lifecycle ...
            pause();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(imagePause);
```

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen after pressing the pause button? You say you want to pause the libgdx lifecycle. How are you planning to resume it afterwards?

Comment: When I press the pause button, I want to pause everything in Libgdx and I want to display a pause menu with a play button. I am planning to resume the lifecycle when the user close the pause menu by clicking on the play button.

Comment: You cannot display anything, when the libgdx lifecycle is completely stopped. Just set a `paused` variable, check that in your `render()` method and skip all gameplay stuff in case it's paused. Also display your pause menu.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're getting thrown by the word pause being used as the name of a lifecycle event. You don't want to mess with that. Create your own type of pause that changes what's happening in the render loop, like @noone said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **goal** is to **stop** the **render**:

To stop the render:

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
```

To put it back on:

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);
```

To trigger render when the rendering is stop:

```
Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

Documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering

Hope it will help you.